# SharePoint Online remote authentication

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hi I am trying SharePoint Online remote authentication
Followed couple of options as given in the link below
https://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/

I am using sharepoint online. Can someone help me do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could get c# code [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-access-d224a674), I used the code before.